# Hyperparameter Optimization in sklearn and n_jobs > 1: Pickling

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiprocessing, pickle, keras

I'm in a "pickle". Here's the structure of my code:

- A base class that acts like an abstract class
- A subclass that can be instantiated

  - A method that sets up the parameters and calls `RandomizedSearchCV` or `GridSearchCV` with `n_jobs=-1`.

    - A local function, `create_model`, that creates the neural network model (see [this](http://machinelearningmastery.com/grid-search-hyperparameters-deep-learning-models-python-keras/) tutorial) to be called by `KerasClassifier` or `KerasRegressor`

I get an error saying local object can't be pickled. If I change `n_jobs=1`, then no problems. So I suspect the issue is with the local function and parallel processing. Is there a fix to this? After googling a bit, it seems that the serializer `dill` could work here (I even found a package called `multiprocessing_on_dill`). But I'm currently relying on `sklearn`'s packages.

Comment: You can monkeypatch joblib and make it run on dill. Not an ideal solution though.

Comment: Yeah, I'm more interested in a solution that doesn't require patching others' code like that... :/

Comment: Which `backend` do you use?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko: For `Keras`? I'd like to try both TensorFlow and Theano. Does it impact that error at all?

Comment: For `Theano` it's impossible to run model training / evaluation in parallel.

Comment: Oh, is that true? So for Theano, I can't have `n_jobs=-1`, correct?

Comment: Using TensorFlow as backend also produces the same error (can't pickle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a "solution" to my problem. I was really puzzled why the examples [here](http://machinelearningmastery.com/grid-search-hyperparameters-deep-learning-models-python-keras/) work with `n_jobs=-1`, but my code doesn't. It seems the issue is with the local function `create_model` that resides in a method of the subclass. If I make the local function a method of the subclass, I'm able to set `n_jobs > 1`.

So to recap, here's the structure of my code:

- A base class that acts like an abstract class
- A subclass that can be instantiated

  - A method that sets up the parameters and calls `RandomizedSearchCV` or `GridSearchCV` with `n_jobs=-1`.
  - A **method**, `create_model`, that creates the neural network model to be called by `KerasClassifier` or `KerasRegressor`

General idea of the code:

```
from abc import ABCMeta
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, RandomizedSearchCV

class MLAlgorithms(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    def __init__(self, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test=None):
        """
        Constructor with train and test data.
        :param X_train: Train descriptor data
        :param y_train: Train observed data
        :param X_test: Test descriptor data
        :param y_test: Test observed data
        """
        ...

    @abstractmethod
    def setmlalg(self, mlalg):
        """
        Sets a machine learning algorithm.
        :param mlalg: Dictionary of the machine learning algorithm.
        """
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def fitmlalg(self, mlalg, rid=None):
        """
        Fits a machine learning algorithm.
        :param mlalg: Machine learning algorithm
        """
        pass


class MLClassification(MLAlgorithms):
    """
    Main class for classification machine learning algorithms.
    """

    def setmlalg(self, mlalg):
        """
        Sets a classification machine learning algorithm.
        :param mlalg: Dictionary of the classification machine learning algorithm.
        """
        ...

    def fitmlalg(self, mlalg):
        """
        Fits a classification machine learning algorithm.
        :param mlalg: Classification machine learning algorithm
        """
        ...

    # Function to create model, required for KerasClassifier
    def create_model(self, n_layers=1, units=10, input_dim=10, output_dim=1,
                     optimizer="rmsprop", loss="binary_crossentropy",
                     kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform", activation="sigmoid",
                     kernel_regularizer="l2", kernel_regularizer_weight=0.01,
                     lr=0.01, momentum=0.0, decay=0.0, nesterov=False, rho=0.9, epsilon=1E-8,
                     beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, schedule_decay=0.004):
        from keras.models import Sequential
        from keras.layers import Dense
        from keras import regularizers, optimizers

        # Create model
        if kernel_regularizer.lower() == "l1":
            kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l1(l=kernel_regularizer_weight)
        elif kernel_regularizer.lower() == "l2":
            kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(l=kernel_regularizer_weight)
        elif kernel_regularizer.lower() == "l1_l2":
            kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l1_l2(l1=kernel_regularizer_weight, l2=kernel_regularizer_weight)
        else:
            print("Warning: Kernel regularizer {0} not supported. Using default 'l2' regularizer.".format(
                kernel_regularizer))
            kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(l=kernel_regularizer_weight)

        if optimizer.lower() == "sgd":
            optimizer = optimizers.sgd(lr=lr, momentum=momentum, decay=decay, nesterov=nesterov)
        elif optimizer.lower() == "rmsprop":
            optimizer = optimizers.rmsprop(lr=lr, rho=rho, epsilon=epsilon, decay=decay)
        elif optimizer.lower() == "adagrad":
            optimizer = optimizers.adagrad(lr=lr, epsilon=epsilon, decay=decay)
        elif optimizer.lower() == "adadelta":
            optimizer = optimizers.adadelta(lr=lr, rho=rho, epsilon=epsilon, decay=decay)
        elif optimizer.lower() == "adam":
            optimizer = optimizers.adam(lr=lr, beta_1=beta_1, beta_2=beta_2, epsilon=epsilon, decay=decay)
        elif optimizer.lower() == "adamax":
            optimizer = optimizers.adamax(lr=lr, beta_1=beta_1, beta_2=beta_2, epsilon=epsilon, decay=decay)
        elif optimizer.lower() == "nadam":
            optimizer = optimizers.nadam(lr=lr, beta_1=beta_1, beta_2=beta_2, epsilon=epsilon,
                                         schedule_decay=schedule_decay)
        else:
            print("Warning: Optimizer {0} not supported. Using default 'sgd' optimizer.".format(optimizer))
            optimizer = "sgd"

        model = Sequential()
        model.add(
            Dense(units=units, input_dim=input_dim,
                  kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, activation=activation,
                  kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer))
        for layer_count in range(n_layers - 1):
            model.add(
                Dense(units=units, kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, activation=activation,
                      kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer))
        model.add(Dense(units=output_dim,
                        kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, activation=activation,
                        kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer))

        # Compile model
        model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model


class MLRegression(MLAlgorithms):
    """
    Main class for regression machine learning algorithms.
    """
    ...
```

Comment: I am very interested in this issue but I can't seem to understand how your code is being organised. Do you have an example of the abstract class?

Comment: I updated my answer with part of the code. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks mate! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm the same problem when running sklearn's grid search on a kerasClassifier model with parallelization (n_jobs>1) on Windows in a jupyter notebook/ipython (no problem on Unix).

I solved the issue by putting the create_model function that causes the pickle problem into a module and importing the module instead of defining the function within the environment.

To create a simple module for Python,

- create a text file in the same folder you're running the main code from and save it as my_module.py
- put the definition of the create_model function into the file
- instead of defining create_model in your code, import the module with `import my_module` and call your function from the module with `my_module.create_model()`